# Стилизация input checkbox

Tags: html, css, input

Доброго времени суток уважаемые жители Stackoverflow!
Не получается стилизовать чекбокс так, как нужно, а именно, чтобы галочка исчезала и появлялась при нажатии. Также непонятно почему при добавлении кода сюда галочка повернулась, у меня все отображается корректно.
Буду очень благодарен если поможете разобраться.

```css
.container-checkbox__input {
  display: none;
}

.container-checkbox__input:checked+.container-checkbox__label::after {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.container-checkbox__label {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container-checkbox__label::before {
  content: "";
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-right: 16px;
  flex: 0 0 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.container-checkbox__label::after {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 13px;
  height: 9px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  border: 1.8px solid #000000;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<input class="container-checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="subscription" id="check" checked>
<label class="container-checkbox__label" for="checkbox">Я согласен с условиями обработки данных</label>
```

Comment: Какого результата вы хотите добиться?

Comment: При нажатии на чекбокс галочка пропадает и наоборот

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```css
.container-checkbox {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container-checkbox__input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container-checkbox__icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.container-checkbox__icon::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 13px;
  height: 9px;  
  border: 1.8px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.container-checkbox__input:checked ~ .container-checkbox__icon::after{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<label class="container-checkbox">
  <input class="container-checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="subscription">
  <span class="container-checkbox__icon"></span>
  <span class="container-checkbox__text">Я согласен с условиями обработки данных</span>
</label>

<label class="container-checkbox">
  <input class="container-checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="subscription" checked>
  <span class="container-checkbox__icon"></span>
  <span class="container-checkbox__text">Я согласен с условиями обработки данных</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо! Да прибудет с вами сила :D